# why the logical call context must be serializable?

Tags: c#, .net

Below is some code from a book:

```
public static void Main() {
   // Put some data into the Main thread's logical call context
   CallContext.LogicalSetData("Name", "Jeffrey");

   // Initiate some work to be done by a thread pool thread
   // The thread pool thread can access the logical call context data 
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", CallContext.LogicalGetData("Name")));
   ...
}
```

and the author says:

> The items that you add to the logical call context must be serializable. Flowing an execution context that contains logical call context data items can hurt performance dramatically, because capturing the execution context requires serializing and deserializing all the data items.

So if I want to pass a custom class instance to the call context, the code has to be like:

```
public static void Main() {
   // Put some data into the Main thread's logical call context
   CallContext.LogicalSetData("Name", new Person());

   // Initiate some work to be done by a thread pool thread
   // The thread pool thread can access the logical call context data 
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", CallContext.LogicalGetData("Name")));
   ...
}

[Serializable]
class Person {
   ...
}
```

So the Person class has to be serializable (uses the `Serializable` attribute on top of it).

But why execution context is designed to serialize and deserialize data items? Why it is not to be designed just like passing a reference parameter to a fuction? In this way, execution context doesn't need to serialize and deserialize objects since they already exists in heap, so all execution context needs is just the reference of these objects?

Comment: question: did you try *not* making `Person` serializable? did it work?

Comment: @MarcGravell so why the author says "execution context requires serializing and deserializing all the data items"?

Comment: either they're outright incorrect, or they're talking about a specific *scenario* when it needs to be serilaizable (presumably: remoting), or: it has changed since the author wrote that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for the payload to be serializable; the following works fine:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;
static class P
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Put some data into the Main thread's logical call context
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("Name", new Person("Fred"));

        // Initiate some work to be done by a thread pool thread
        // The thread pool thread can access the logical call context data 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            _ => Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", CallContext.LogicalGetData("Name")));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Person // note: not [Serializable]
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Person(string name) => Name = name;
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Ultimately, the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext` API was designed with additional requirements in mind, in particular: remoting. Since that doesn't apply here, quite simply: **don't use that API**. The most appropriate API for your example would seem to be `AsyncLocal<T>`, which provides an abstraction over the same concept:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
static class P
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<Person> s_name = new();
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Put some data into the async-local state
        s_name.Value = new Person("Jeffrey");
        
        // Initiate some work to be done by a thread pool thread
        // The thread pool thread can access the async-local state
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            _ => Console.WriteLine($"Name={s_name.Value.Name}"));

        Console.ReadLine(); // keep process alive
    }

    class Person // note: not [Serializable]
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Person(string name) => Name = name;
    }
}
```